# LabelBinarizer gives too many features on test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing, data-leakage

Let's say I have a Dataset with a coulum called countries. Lots of the values are `usa` and there is a small amount of values wich are either `ger` or `fra`.

Let's also assume `train_test_split` gives me the following setup

```
X_train=DataFrame({'country': ['usa']*95+['fra']*5})
X_test=DataFrame({'country': ['usa']*2+['ger']*1+['fra']*3})
y_train=DataFrame({'y': [1]*95+[0]*5})
y_test=DataFrame({'y': [1]*2+[0]*1+[1]*3})
```

Now I am creating a `LabelBinarizer()` and fit the `X_train` on it. Afterwards I run a logistic regression

```
country_binarizer=LabelBinarizer().fit(X_train)
log_reg=LogisticRegression().fit(country_binarizer.transform(X_train),y_train)
```

When I now try to predict the accuracy of the Model on the test set i get a `ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 1`, since the `country_binarizer` returns a Matrix with shape `(6,2)`

```
 log_reg.score(country_binarizer.transform(X_test), y_test)
```

How could i tackle this problem. Fitting the LabelBinarizer on the whole Dataset would result in data leakage, or does it?